# legend changes unexpectedly with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Any idea why this happens? Reversing the order of the legend changes it quite substantially.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour = disp, size = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "PuOr") + 
  guides(size = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, colour = disp, size = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "PuOr") + 
  guides(size = FALSE, colour = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: `guide_colorbar`

Comment: @user20650 thanks, that fixes it alright, but do you know why this happens by default?

Comment: @RobertMc: not sure I understand the question. A colorbar is fundamentally a different way of visualising how the scale works compared to a legend that shows a few distinct values in a key. There may be some way of using both a colorbar and a legend, but otherwise when you told ggplot to use a legend for the colour scale, it used that instead of the colorbar.

Comment: It would seem `guide_colorbar` is for continuous and `guide_legend` is for discrete.  The last example here - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/guides - is a mix of the two.

Comment: The docs for `guide_colorbar` mention that it's for continuous values, but I don't see `guide_legend` saying the same for discrete values. Thanks though, I hadn't noticed that difference before.